# User is not able to "signin with Google" using Cy.origin in cypress

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress, gui-testing

I'm getting this error while running the below code.

> Timed out retrying after 4000ms: The command was expected to run against origin https://google.com but the application is at origin https://google.com. This commonly happens when you have either not navigated to the expected origin or have navigated away unexpectedly.

```
it("Login with Google",()=>{
        cy.visit("/", {failOnStatusCode: false})
        cy.get("[href='/login/google']").click()
        cy.origin("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth", function(){
            cy.get("#identifierId").type("Testuser")
         })
```

It's working for login with github but not for Google. . .Don't know why not working for Google. I know there is solution available on Cypress official docs to do it programatically but requirement is to do using UI.

Someone suggested to use another solution  'Cypress plugin for social media login'
https://github.com/lirantal/cypress-social-logins

but it's also not working for me. I'm facing this issue in image.
[image]

This issue is also reported on "Cypress plugin for social media login" github repo issues.
This plugin is also not working for login with Facebook for me. (if working for someone else please let me know)

Answer (score 0):

use firefox browser to run the test. it will be resolved.